# Error with UserTypeCollection

Tags: hibernate, jpa

I have followed [this tutorial](http://www.javalobby.org/java/forums/m91832311.html) to implement my custom collection.

I have also annotated the corresponding property of my entity like so :

```
  @OneToMany(cascade = ALL, mappedBy = "plan", fetch = EAGER, orphanRemoval = true)
  @CollectionType(type = "my.namespace.MyCustomCollectionType")
  public MyCustomCollection getThings() {
    return things;
  }
```

However, when creating the mapping, Hibernate complains with :

```
 Illegal attempt to map a non collection as a @OneToMany, @ManyToMany or @CollectionOfElements
```

According to [Hibernate documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.6/reference/en-US/html/collections.html), this should be ok. I should be able to use my custom collection in the method signature, since I use a custom collection type annotation :

> The actual interface might be java.util.Set, java.util.Collection, java.util.List, java.util.Map, java.util.SortedSet,
>   java.util.SortedMap or anything you like ("anything you like" means
>   you will have to write an implementation of
>   org.hibernate.usertype.UserCollectionType).

I don't know what is wrong.

Comment: Does `my.namespace.MyCustomCollectionType` inherit or implement `MyCustomCollection`? It should...

Comment: your method signature should be like `public List<MyCustomCollection> getThings()`

Comment: @yair No, it implements UserCollectionType. I don't think it needs to extends MyCustomCollection. I tried to do so and it does not fix the problem.

Comment: well somthing isn't clear. Do you have two classes - `my.namespace.MyCustomCollectionType` and `MyCustomCollection`? If so, why? And what is the relation between them?

Answer (score 1):

Ok I figured out my problem.

First, to be more clear, yes I have 2 classes. 
The first one is my custom collection (**MyCustomCollection**), the other one extends [UserTypeCollection](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.2/api/org/hibernate/usertype/UserCollectionType.html) (**MyCustomCollectionType**), which is a technical interface needed by Hibernate in order to support a custom collection.

Anyway, I have figured out what is wrong :

- First, Hibernate only support interfaces in method signatures for collections, so I wrote **ICustomCollection**. And then I needed to declare a [PersistentCollection](http://www.dil.univ-mrs.fr/~massat/docs/hibernate-2/api/net/sf/hibernate/collection/PersistentCollection.html)
  ([PersistentSet](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.2/api/org/hibernate/collection/PersistentSet.html) in my case), that extends this interface.
- Then the **MyCustomCollectionType** should return this custom Persistent Set.

I figured it out by looking at the test suite in Hibernate. [There are a couple of examples](http://kickjava.com/src/org.hibernate.test.usercollection.index.htm)

But sadly, the **PersistentSet** extends a non-generic set, and thus, oblige you to declare a non-generic collection as well.

Here is a [Jira bug for it](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-2054). It's been here for a while.